# start two applications on the same apache http server

Tags: apache, redhat

I'm working on two applications and I've put them on the same Apache server.
I have created for each application a file on conf and bin:
apache/conf/httpd_app1.conf    : application1
apache/conf/httpd_app2.conf    : application2

apache/bin/apachectl_app1
apache/bin/apachectl_app2

I configured the Virtual Host of each one,

but when I point to the first application, it re-directs me to the other and sometimes the other way around.
I don't understand what I missed and what I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

add this code to httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@www1.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/www/vhosts/www1"
    ServerName www1.example.com
    ErrorLog "/www/logs/www1/error_log"
    CustomLog "/www/logs/www1/access_log" combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.50:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@www2.example.org
    DocumentRoot "/www/vhosts/www2"
    ServerName www2.example.org
    ErrorLog "/www/logs/www2/error_log"
    CustomLog "/www/logs/www2/access_log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```